# use parameters in a Cte

Tags: sql-server

I want to use parameters in the below cte but I get the below error messages

- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure X82 7 Days/by Day, Line 5
  Incorrect syntax near '('.
- Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure X82 7 Days/by Day, Line 21
  Must declare the scalar variable "@startDate".

Once I can get the perameters to work I will turn the static pivot into a dynamic one

```
    ALTER Procedure [dbo].[X82 7 Days/by Day] 
            (
            @StartDate As datetime = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()-8), 0)
            ,@EndDate As datetime = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @startdate -1), 0)
            )
    As
    Begin   

    ;with cte as(

    select  [CAB Part No.]
        ,[RFT/Scrap/Rework]
        ,[Process No.]
        ,[Process]
        ,[Date & Time]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,cast([Date & Time] as date) UtcDay
    from    [SFDLOG]
    where   [Date & Time] between @startDate and @EndDate
    )
    select  [CAB Part No.]
        ,[RFT/Scrap/Rework]
        ,[Process No.]
        ,[Process]
        ,[Quantity]
        ,UtcDay
    into #TempDates
    from cte

    select *
    from
    (
    select   [Quantity]
        ,[utcday]
        ,[CAB Part No.]
        ,[Process No.]
        ,[Process]
        ,[RFT/Scrap/Rework]
    from #tempDates
     ) x
    pivot
    (
    count([Quantity])
    for [utcDay]
    In ([2015-02-01],[2015-02-02],[2015-02-03],[2015-02-04],[2015-02-05],[2015-02-06],[2015-02-07])
    )p

    Order By [CAB Part No.],[Process No.]

    drop table #tempdates
```

End

Answer (score 2):

The first error is on Line 5, telling you that you cannot use Functions in your parameter's default values.

Pass in `NULL` as the default value, then sort the parameters out inside the Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
(
  @StartDate As datetime = NULL 
  ,@EndDate As datetime = NULL 
)
AS

BEGIN

-- If you're using SQL Server 2008 or greater use DATEADD(DAY, -8, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
IF @StartDate IS NULL
  SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()-8), 0);

-- If you're using SQL Server 2008 or greater use DATEADD(DAY, -1, @StartDate)
IF @EndDate IS NULL
  SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @startdate -1), 0);


END
```

Once you have fixed this issue, and capitalise the `@startDate` parameter to read `@StartDate`, you should be fine.

For reference, there's an open [Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters) (currently 7 years old) that is Microsoft acknowledging it's on their 'ToDo' list.

Comment: And BoL is again [not precise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx "CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL), see Arguments"): `The default value must be a constant or it can be NULL.` Nothing about letting you reference any of the already parsed parameters.

Comment: As for the Connect item, I think it's about a different issue. It's about using functions when *calling* a stored procedure, and the OP wants to use functions in a specific place of a *declaration*.